# Return the index of the first occurence the bit ‘pattern’ is found in num

Tags: c++, c, bit-shift, bit, bitset

Find_sequence (unsigned int num, unsigned int pattern) returns the index of the first occurence the bit ‘pattern’ is found in num. 
e.g. the bits in num = 10010 and pattern = 1001 should return 1 because the pattern was found at index 1 in num.

Well I dont know how to implement it though. I tried different ways but it does not work....Any help will appreciated. Sorry if this question is simple. I just started learning bits thing.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: I know it's not a code writing service. I just started using Stackoverflow and have no idea about it. We just covered bits today in class and our professor directly gave us this question. We just covered the basics. I already spent 2 hours before asking here

Comment: In that case please post what you've tried. We can't help if you don't show us what you've attempted.

Comment: You need to help us by at least explaining what you have tried, or thought about and what specifically you don't understand. For example, have you covered C bitwise operators? If not, then go learn that. If already covered then explain what specific difficulty you have in applying that to your problem - by showing the code you have tried. You'll usually get more help on SO if you have demonstrated your efforts and have a specific question.

Comment: What will be helpful is a loop that employs a right shift `>` and a bitwise `&` with the pattern to determine if there is a match.  If there is a match, the index will be the loop count at the time it tests true.